# Codeigniter- Bootstrap Popover Unable to save data

Tags: php, twitter-bootstrap, codeigniter

I am trying to save data inserted from a modal. I have tried the script in localhost its works perfect. After upload to Production, The "note" field not save into DB table. But my hidden type='hidden' name='leaveID' manage to save in DB table. Not sure why? Please help...

Below is my view file..

```
    <button type="button" class="btn-cs btn-sm-cs" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal"  data-html="true" href="#" id="modal"><span class="fa fa-pencil"></span> Note</button>
                 <!-- Modal -->
  <div class="modal fade" id="myModal" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog">

      <!-- Modal content-->
      <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
          <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>

           <form  action="<?php echo base_url('leave/note'); ?>" id="formid" method="POST"  >

        <textarea class="form-control" id="note" name="note" ><?=set_value('note')?></textarea>
         <input type='hidden' name='leaveID' value="<?= set_value("leaveID", $leave->leaveID) ?>" />

        </div>
          <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="submit" name="submit" class="btn btn-info " >Add Note</button></div>



        </div>

    </form>

     <script>
    $("[data-toggle=modal]").popover({
    html: true, 
    content: function() {
          return $('#modal-header').html();
        }
});
     </script>


      </div>

    </div><?php } ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Manage to solve the issue. Just has some permission issue.